# AngularJS Form Validation and Submit Issue

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm currently developing an [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) application which allows the user to activate their account, input user data and submit JSON data on completion.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
If user data is valid *(within the JSON data)* redirect to '/form/' on submit else display invalid error message 'Invalid Account'.

**Current Problems:**
**1.** If the user enters the correct Membership and Activation number first the user is redirect to '/form/' but if the user enters the incorrect details then enters the correct details the redirect doesn't work.
**2.** I tried implementing an invalid alert to a if else statement but was alerted within 4/5 alerts at the same time, Unsure why this was happening?

I'm developing this project on Plnkr, please feel free to assist and point me in the right direct. Thank you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/5uPSn2ae0yFjYzujPFWm?p=preview

```
  $scope.findMembership = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.membershipData.membershipNumber, function(value, key) {
      if (key === $scope.membershipValue && value[0].activationNumber === $scope.activationValue) {
        $location.path("/form/");
      }
    });
  };
```

**Update**

```
formCtrl.controller('activation', function($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
  var normalized = Object.keys($scope.membershipData.membershipNumber).map(function(k) {
    return { key : k, val : $scope.membershipData.membershipNumber[k][0].activationNumber }
  });

  normalized = [
    {"key":"541","val":"541X"},
    {"key":"4692","val":"4692X"},
    {"key":"45165","val":"45165X"},
    {"key":"5464565","val":"5464565X"},
    {"key":"54645651","val":"54645651X"},
    {"key":"D4554160N","val":"D4554160NX"}
  ]

  $scope.findMembership = function() {
      if (normalized.some(function(o) {
        return o.key == $scope.membershipValue && o.val == $scope.activationValue
      })) $location.path("/form/")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your otherwise block to this:

```
    otherwise({
  templateUrl: 'view/activation.html',
  controller: 'activation'
});
```

I think the redirect is causing the app to not be able to find the template it's looking for. Also I'd avoid using the $location.path() method inside the angular.forEach loop. Maybe normalize the data to a true array so you can use Array.some() instead.

Something like this:

```
var normalized = Object.keys($scope.membershipData.membershipNumber).map(function(k) {
  return { key : k, val : $scope.membershipData.membershipNumber[k][0].activationNumber }
});

/*
  normalized = [
    {"key":"541","val":"541X"},
    {"key":"4692","val":"4692X"},
    {"key":"45165","val":"45165X"},
    {"key":"5464565","val":"5464565X"},
    {"key":"54645651","val":"54645651X"},
    {"key":"D4554160N","val":"D4554160NX"}
  ]
*/

$scope.findMembership = function() {
    if (normalized.some(function(o) {
      return o.key == $scope.membershipValue && o.val == $scope.activationValue
    })) $location.path("/form/")
}
```